# Não estou conseguindo adicionar uma referência ao meu programa

Tags: c#, .net

Estou precisando utilizar [esta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector3(v=vs.111).aspx) estrutura. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo acha-la no .NET Framework. Já adicionei uma referência para `System.Numerics` e coloquei o `using`, mas mesmo assim não consigo usar. Tentei também adicionar uma referencia para o `System.Numerics.Vectors` e colocar `using System.Numerics.Vectors`, mas aparece que os 2 nem sequer existem.

**Tentando utilizar:**

[image: Ilustração]

**Tentando adicionar referência para `System.Numerics.Vectors`:**

[image: Ilustração]

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Como consertar?

Comment: Adicionou a dll system.numerics.vector?

Comment: Não sei se estou fazendo errado, mas dê uma olhada na segunda imagem da pergunta. Ela não aparece ali.

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que ela está em uma das abas. De qualquer forma, você pode baixar pelo nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors)

Comment: @LINQ Não tem, procurei em todas antes de fazer a pergunta. Instalei o nuget aqui, mas quando eu for abrir o software, eu vou precisar da dll junto?

Comment: Vai sim, cara. Mas a DLL vai ficar na pasta `bin` junto com as outras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar baixar a DLL pelo [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors)

> ```
> PM> Install-Package System.Numerics.Vectors
> ```